# Wind speed and molecule drift speed

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, low-temperature-physics

My question regards [this answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/8302), more precisely this assertion:

> If all the air molecules, by some strange coincidence, all moved in the same direction 2 things would happen. One, the air would get very cold as temperature is essentially agitated molecules moving or vibrating against each other, and two, the wind speed would be over 1000 kph. Roughly the speed of sound. Fortunately this kind of thing is so statistically improbable it essentially never happens.

I'm skeptical that this is correct. As far as I know, when approaching absolute zero, Brownian motion vanishes and any real gas turns into a liquid.

Yet, isn't also the drift velocity of, say N<sub>2</sub> molecules at lowest technically possible temperatures, still directly related to flow velocity of the liquid nitrogen?

Answer (score 0):

The question you are referring to was if we can view wind as (mainly nitrogen) particles moving, in average, in one direction. The answer stated correctly, that you can picture wind as Brownian motion plus drift. All considerations here are at room temperature, not at temperatures close to absolute zero.

The statement that "the air would get very cold" if all particles would move in the same direction is debatable. I would argue it is just an extremely unlikely fluctuation of a room-temperature system. In any case, this sentence does not consider condensation of nitrogen or flow of liquid nitrogen.